# How to compile gutenprint in Raspbian?

Tags: pi-3, cups

The official README from SourceForge said,

```
./configure
make
make install
```

From the [SVN exported files](https://sourceforge.net/p/gimp-print/source/ci/master/tree/) there is no `./configure` and `INSTALL`, but with `./autogen.sh`, `Makefile.ac` and `configure.ac` present I assume `automake` and `autoconf` here, and so I tried.

1. `autoconf` and `./configure` finished without errors.
2. `make check` generates loads of notes and warnings but no errors.
3. `make install` fails with no obvious fixable errors.

Here is the full output in step 3, but I have no clue on what exactly has happened.

```
Making install in include
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include'
Making install in gutenprint
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include/gutenprint'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include/gutenprint'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/gutenprint'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 gutenprint-version.h '/usr/local/include/gutenprint'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/gutenprint'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 gutenprint.h gutenprint-module.h array.h bit-ops.h channel.h color.h curve-cache.h curve.h dither.h image.h list.h module.h mxml.h paper.h path.h printers.h sequence.h string-list.h util.h vars.h weave.h xml.h '/usr/local/include/gutenprint'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include/gutenprint'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include/gutenprint'
Making install in gutenprintui2
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include/gutenprintui2'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include/gutenprintui2'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include/gutenprintui2'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include/gutenprintui2'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/include'
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src'
Making install in main
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/main'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/main'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libgutenprint.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libgutenprint.so.2.4.0 /usr/local/lib/libgutenprint.so.2.4.0
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libgutenprint.so.2.4.0 libgutenprint.so.2 || { rm -f libgutenprint.so.2 && ln -s libgutenprint.so.2.4.0 libgutenprint.so.2; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libgutenprint.so.2.4.0 libgutenprint.so || { rm -f libgutenprint.so && ln -s libgutenprint.so.2.4.0 libgutenprint.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libgutenprint.lai /usr/local/lib/libgutenprint.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libgutenprint.a /usr/local/lib/libgutenprint.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libgutenprint.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/libgutenprint.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 gutenprint.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/main'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/main'
Making install in xml
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml'
Making install in escp2
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2'
Making install in inks
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/inks'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/inks'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/inks'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 artisan.xml b500.xml c120.xml c64.xml c80.xml c82.xml claria.xml cmy.xml cmykrb.xml cmykro.xml cx3650.xml defaultblack.xml f360.xml f360_photo.xml f360_photo7_japan.xml f360_ultrachrome.xml f360_ultrachrome_k3.xml f360_ultrachrome_k3v.xml f360_ultrachrome_k3v_2.xml nx100.xml photo_gen0.xml photo_gen1.xml photo_gen2.xml photo_gen3.xml photo_gen3_4.xml photo_gen4.xml photo_pigment.xml picturemate_4.xml picturemate_6.xml pro_gen1.xml pro_gen2.xml pro_pigment.xml pro_ultrachrome.xml pro_ultrachrome_k3.xml pro_ultrachrome_k34.xml pro_ultrachrome_k3v.xml pro_ultrachrome_k3v4.xml pro_ultrachrome_k3v10.xml standard.xml standard_gen0.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/inks'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 sx445.xml ultrachrome.xml wf40.xml wf500.xml x80.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/inks'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/inks'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/inks'
Making install in inputslots
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/inputslots'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/inputslots'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/inputslots'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 artisan.xml b500.xml cd.xml cd_cutter_roll_feed.xml cd_roll_feed.xml cutter_roll_feed.xml default.xml default-duplex.xml pro3880.xml pro_roll_feed.xml pro_cutter_roll_feed.xml r1800.xml r2400.xml r2880.xml rx680.xml rx700.xml spro5000.xml standard_roll_feed.xml wf7000.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/inputslots'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/inputslots'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/inputslots'
Making install in model
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/model'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/model'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/model'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 model_0.xml model_1.xml model_2.xml model_3.xml model_4.xml model_5.xml model_6.xml model_7.xml model_8.xml model_9.xml model_10.xml model_11.xml model_12.xml model_13.xml model_14.xml model_15.xml model_16.xml model_17.xml model_18.xml model_19.xml model_20.xml model_21.xml model_22.xml model_23.xml model_24.xml model_25.xml model_26.xml model_27.xml model_28.xml model_29.xml model_30.xml model_31.xml model_32.xml model_33.xml model_34.xml model_35.xml model_36.xml model_37.xml model_38.xml model_39.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/model'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 model_40.xml model_41.xml model_42.xml model_43.xml model_44.xml model_45.xml model_46.xml model_47.xml model_48.xml model_49.xml model_50.xml model_51.xml model_52.xml model_53.xml model_54.xml model_55.xml model_56.xml model_57.xml model_58.xml model_59.xml model_60.xml model_61.xml model_62.xml model_63.xml model_64.xml model_65.xml model_66.xml model_67.xml model_68.xml model_69.xml model_70.xml model_71.xml model_72.xml model_73.xml model_74.xml model_75.xml model_76.xml model_77.xml model_78.xml model_79.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/model'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 model_80.xml model_81.xml model_82.xml model_83.xml model_84.xml model_85.xml model_86.xml model_87.xml model_88.xml model_89.xml model_90.xml model_91.xml model_92.xml model_93.xml model_94.xml model_95.xml model_96.xml model_97.xml model_98.xml model_99.xml model_100.xml model_101.xml model_102.xml model_103.xml model_104.xml model_105.xml model_106.xml model_107.xml model_108.xml model_109.xml model_110.xml model_111.xml model_112.xml model_113.xml model_114.xml model_115.xml model_116.xml model_117.xml model_118.xml model_119.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/model'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 model_120.xml model_121.xml model_122.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/model'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/model'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/model'
Making install in media
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/media'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/media'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/media'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 artisan.xml b500.xml c120.xml c64.xml c80.xml c82.xml claria.xml claria1400.xml cmy.xml cmykrb.xml cmykro.xml cx3650.xml f360.xml f360_photo.xml f360_photo7_japan.xml f360_ultrachrome.xml f360_ultrachrome_k3.xml f360_ultrachrome_k3v.xml nx100.xml photo_gen0.xml photo_gen1.xml photo_gen2.xml photo_gen3.xml photo_gen3_4.xml photo_gen4.xml photo_pigment.xml picturemate_4.xml picturemate_6.xml pro3880_ultrachrome_k3v.xml pro_gen1.xml pro_gen2.xml pro_pigment.xml pro_ultrachrome.xml pro_ultrachrome_k3.xml pro_ultrachrome_k3v.xml pro_ultrachrome_k3v10.xml r800.xml standard.xml standard_gen0.xml ultrachrome.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/media'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 wf500.xml x80.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/media'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/media'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/media'
Making install in mediasizes
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/mediasizes'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/mediasizes'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/mediasizes'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 standard.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/mediasizes'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/mediasizes'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/mediasizes'
Making install in qualitypresets
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/qualitypresets'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/qualitypresets'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/qualitypresets'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 p1_5.xml picturemate.xml prox900.xml standard.xml v2880.xml wf40.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/qualitypresets'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/qualitypresets'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/qualitypresets'
Making install in weaves
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/weaves'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/weaves'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/weaves'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 pro7000.xml pro7500.xml pro7600.xml standard.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/escp2/weaves'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/weaves'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2/weaves'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml/escp2'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 dither-matrix-1x1.xml dither-matrix-2x1.xml dither-matrix-4x1.xml papers.xml printers.xml '/usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/xml'
Making install in gutenprintui2
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/gutenprintui2'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/gutenprintui2'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/gutenprintui2'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/gutenprintui2'
Making install in escputil
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/escputil'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/escputil'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c escputil '/usr/local/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/escputil /usr/local/bin/escputil
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/escputil'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/escputil'
Making install in gimp2
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/gimp2'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/gimp2'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/gimp2'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/gimp2'
Making install in cups
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/cups'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/cups'
make  install-exec-hook
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/cups'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-hook'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/cups'
if test -n "" -a -n "" ; then \
  /bin/mkdir -p /usr/share/cups/model/gutenprint/5.2/; \
  cd ppd ; \
  for language in * ; do \
    cd ..; \
    /bin/mkdir -p /usr/share/cups/model/gutenprint/5.2//$language; \
    cd ppd/$language; \
    for ppdfile in * ; do \
      (cd ../..; /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ppd/$language/$ppdfile /usr/share/cups/model/gutenprint/5.2//$language) ; \
    done; \
  cd ..; \
  done \
fi
/bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/locale"
for file in ./../../po/*.po; do \
  lang=`basename $file .po`; \
  /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/locale/$lang"; \
  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 $file "/usr/local/share/locale/$lang/gutenprint_$lang.po"; \
done
make  install-data-hook
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/cups'
Expect a number of "rmdir: Directory not empty" warnings
These messages are harmless and should be ignored.
rmdir /usr/share/cups/model/gutenprint/5.2/
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/cups/model/gutenprint/5.2/': No such file or directory
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir /usr/share/cups
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/cups': Directory not empty
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir /usr/lib/cups/driver
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/lib/cups/driver': Directory not empty
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir /usr/lib/cups/filter
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/lib/cups/filter': Directory not empty
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir 
rmdir: missing operand
Try 'rmdir --help' for more information.
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir 
rmdir: missing operand
Try 'rmdir --help' for more information.
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir /usr/bin
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/bin': Directory not empty
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir /usr/lib/cups
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/lib/cups': Directory not empty
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir /etc/cups
rmdir: failed to remove '/etc/cups': Directory not empty
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir `dirname /usr/share/cups`
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share': Directory not empty
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir `dirname /usr/lib/cups`
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/lib': Directory not empty
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
rmdir `dirname /etc/cups`
rmdir: failed to remove '/etc': Directory not empty
Makefile:1937: recipe for target 'install-data-hook' failed
make[4]: [install-data-hook] Error 1 (ignored)
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/cups'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/cups'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/cups'
Making install in foomatic
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/foomatic'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/foomatic'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
if test -n "" ; then \
  make install-kit FOOMATIC_DB=foomatic-db/gutenprint-ijs.5.2 ; \
  make install-kit FOOMATIC_DB=foomatic-db/gutenprint-ijs-simplified.5.2 ; \
fi
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/foomatic'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/foomatic'
Making install in ghost
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/ghost'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/ghost'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/ghost'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/ghost'
Making install in testpattern
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/testpattern'
  YACC     testpatterny.c
../../scripts/ylwrap: line 176: yacc: command not found
Makefile:799: recipe for target 'testpatterny.c' failed
make[2]: *** [testpatterny.c] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src/testpattern'
Makefile:467: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/gimp-print-source-a3a967a6208fda708707c8eeaaadad6aacff6c3d/src'
Makefile:565: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of @Huczu I finished the compilation by adding missing packages, here is the full list of packages I installed.

**Core build**

```
automake
autopoint
openjade
jade 
sgmltools-lite
byacc
```

**With docs**

```
openjade
jade
docbook-utils
flex
```

**With CUPS**

```
libcups2-dev
libcupsimage2-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an error:

```
yacc: command not found
```

You need to install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install byacc
```

After that run once again `make install` command.

Comment: This gave me a good start, after installing `byacc` I get the same kind of errors complaining about `flex` and `db2html` which I also installed afterwards. I can compile the whole thing till the end.

Comment: When compiling for CUPS, it also requires `libcups2-dev` and `libcupsimage2-dev`.

Comment: @Vicary Please feel free to leave the complete list of requirements in a separate answer.  You may have to wait until tomorrow to do so, I am not sure what the rep bar is for answering your own question immediately.

Comment: @goldilocks So stackexchange does not encourage crediting the original answer which directly leads to my solution?

Comment: @goldilocks I want to accept this after editing.

Comment: *"does not encourage crediting"* -> It is not binary.  This post already has two upvotes.  Huczu may edit in the suggestions, or not (it came to my attention simply because it was in a queue of "suggested edits" I cleared).  Note that as you discovered, this is not a complete answer to your question as is, it simply addresses the first error you encountered.

Comment: @goldilocks fair enough, I'll answer my own question.